# GatsbyJS - Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn'

Tags: npm, dependencies, babeljs, gatsby

I have a website that has been running fine for the last 4 months. Randomly the site stopped deploying on Netlify and I keep getting this error:

```
    Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/helpers/possibleConstructorReturn' in
'D:\Websites\nemesis-cheer\node_modules\react-script-tag\lib'
```

I have tried reinstalling babel, tried downgrading to different versions of babel/runtime, tried clearing cache and redeploying, Even tried reverting to old versions of the repo that I know for a fact deploy successfully and they still failed.

Here is my deploy log:
https://pastebin.com/raw/dH45EtP5

The repo is:
https://github.com/mont266/nemesis-cheerleading

Im really stomped here if anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by reinstalling yarn and doing 'yarn add babel-runtime'. Must've gotten rid of the entire plugin at somepoint by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your `babel/core` dependency.

Now you have it locked to `7.13.8` (according to your [`package-lock.json`](https://github.com/mont266/nemesis-cheerleading/blob/master/package-lock.json#L36)), and it seems that the missing helpers are fixed in the `7.5.5`, according to [this stack trace](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11318).

Comment: But `7.5.5` is older than `7.13.8`...

Comment: Nope, it's not... `13 > 5`

Comment: Well, yes.. that's what makes it older. We count 1,2,3,4,5...11,12,13. `5` came before `13`, hence `5` is older than `13`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try adding `"babel-runtime": "6.26.0"`   to your `package.json`
Maybe it would fix an error for you